# How to get tableview [section] outside of tableview methods?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview calendar with a DidSelectMethod and in this method, I'd like to check if the date selected is == to any of the dates in a tableview (the dates are the tableview's Headers) also in the same view controller and then scroll to that date in the tableview.

I'd like some help thinking through the logic for this. Right now I think I need to somehow get the [section] of the tableview outside the tableview methods but I do not think that is the correct way to do this.

Here's what I'm trying so far:

Collection View Calendar's DidSelect method:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    configureCalendarCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)
    cell?.bounce()
    selectedDate = date

// Check if selectedDate is == to any dates in the tableview 

// First, get the dates from TableView's Data Source. 
// The [datesFromCalendarXML] also make up the Headers of each section in TableView
let datesFromCalendarXML = allEventsInVisibleMonth.map {$0.eventdate}

// Reformat selectedDate from collectionView Calendar to String
let selectedDateToString = formatter.string(from: selectedDate!)

// See if the selected date matches any of the tableview dates
if datesFromCalendarXML.contains(selectedDateToString) {

    // set up tableView's scrollToRow
    // get [section] Int of the datesFromCalendarXML that matches
    // Can I get [section] outside of of tableview?
    let sectionOfDate = 

     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0 , section: sectionOfDate)
      self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

} else {}
```

Looking for a tip on how to go about this.

Comment: You would identify the section based on the date in your source data array for your tableview.

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't use the same [section] Int to call it in collectionView. for example in my tableView's titleForHeader, I have let eventForTheSection = allEventsInVisibleMonth[section]. If there are 4 sections and the date in DidSelect matches the 2nd of 4, how do I call that 2nd [section] outside of my tableview methods and in the collectionview's DidSelectMethod?

Comment: I guess you need to search through your array to find the index of the relevant date.  You haven't shown how your data model is set up, so I can't say more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's I got this to work, in case someone else is looking.

I used .index(of: _) to get the index of the selectedDate in my allEventsInVisibleMonth array, and then used that index for scrollToRow's indexPath: IndexPath.

```
let datesFromCalendarXML = allEventsInVisibleMonth.map {$0.eventdate}
    let selectedDateToString = formatter.string(from: selectedDate!)
    if let index = datesFromCalendarXML.index(of: selectedDateToString) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0 , section: index)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at:
        UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
    }
```